# Angular 9 currency pipe not showing euro symbol

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-pipe

I'd like to format a number with the currency pipe in Angular 9 (https://angular.io/api/common/CurrencyPipe). Therefore I'm doing something like this

```
{{ 999.12 | currency:'EUR' }}
```

within my templates. But the euro sign is never shown. If I change the currency to USD or GBP the $ or £ symbols are shown.
Anyone can help me out?

**Update / Solution**

So it was a Chrome Extension. After accidentally opening the app with a private browser tab the EUR symbol was shown. Therefore I deactivated all chrome extensions in normal user mode and the symbol was shown here too. So after some round of divide and conquer I did manage to find the extension which was causing this bug https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gtmga-debug/ilnpmccnfdjdjjikgkefkcegefikecdc

Comment: I cannot reproduce. It shows € sign at the begging. Any demo? Here is mine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ybbv3q

Comment: So for testing purpose I just did `ng new my-app` and only did put `{{911.121 | currency:'EUR'}}` in the app.component.html. Still the same no currency symbol shown

Comment: Have you set/changed the locals in somewhere?

Comment: Yes, within the original app and within the plain test version

Comment: Thanks bro, I delete the same extension, and it works !

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to pinpoint the error without further details. Try to manually set the locale.

app.module.ts

```js
import { NgModule, LOCALE_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { registerLocaleData } from '@angular/common';
import localeDe from '@angular/common/locales/de';

registerLocaleData(localeDe);

@NgModule({
  providers:    [
    { provide: LOCALE_ID, useValue: 'de-DE' },     // <-- Locale for Germany
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And try the following in the template

```html
{{ 999.12 | currency:'EUR':true }}
```

Comment: I did set the locale via `i18nLocale` in `angular.json`. And I've just tried with your suggested method too. Still no change and no symbol is shown. And as mentioned in here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62181765/angular-9-currency-pipe-not-showing-euro-symbol#comment109976114_62181765 the problem occurs even with a fresh project

Comment: I wonder why we need to say `currency: 'EUR'` after setting the locale? Also it displays `€2.99` for me instead of ``2,99 €`